# Regex for incomplete lines within known start and end strings

Tags: database, regex

I want to insert the following into a database:

> (#text1#,#text2#,#text3#,#text4#,#text5#,#text6#, #text7#, #text8#, #text9#),
>   (#text1#,#text2#,#text3#,#text4#,#text5#,#text6#, #text7#, #text8#, #text9#),
>   (#text1#,#text2#,#text3#,#text4#,#text5#,#text6#, #text7#, #text8#, #text9#);

but sometimes I will not have nine textfields that I can place into my database; e.g.

> (#text1#,#text2#,#text3#,#text4#,#text5#,#text6#, #text7#, #text8#, #text9#),
>   (#text1#,#text2#,#text3#,#text4#,#), <<<--- String breaks and messes up my insert
>   (#text1#,#text2#,#text3#,#text4#,#text5#,#text6#, #text7#, #text8#, #text9#);

What regex will delete lines with fields that don't have both start and end tags? **Edit:** The lines themselves will always have the start tag `(#` and the closing tag `#)`.

I tried `/^\(#.*?#,#.*?#,#.*?#,#.*?#,#.*?#,#.*?#,#.*?#,#.*?#,#.*?#\)$/ig` but it didn't work.

I created [a page where you can insert a regex to see if your solution works](http://online-affiliate-programs.co.za/test/index.asp).

Comment: htstring29.replace(/^\((#.*?# ){0,8}\),$/g, ''); I have tried this and it does not seem to work either?

Comment: It seems to me that the columns in your DB might want to be rows instead (I'd normalize the table, if you have that option)

Comment: Oh how you tempt us with the "expert should solve this in seconds" :)

Comment: I am surprised Person b :-) I thought it is like so easy to do :-)

Comment: +1 for the effort you put in your question : http://online-affiliate-programs.co.za/test/index.asp

Comment: Presumably, the regex should also take care of the other possible source of confusion - extra fields or characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
/^\((?:#.+#,\s*){8}(?:#.+#\s*)\)[,;]$/gm
```

That is 8 non-capturing groups of a text field with one or more characters followed by a comma and optional whitespace, and one more text field with no comma all inside literal parentheses, and followed by a comma or semicolon.  If you have multiple lines in one text string, make sure to use the "/m" switch so that "^" and "$" match newlines.

You should be able to use this to extract all the valid lines.  Deleting other lines is going to be harder...

update:

Got it.  Here's one that matches lines with 8 or fewer pairs of "#" characters, or with an odd number of them:

```
^\((?:[^#\n]*?#[^#\n]*?#[,\s]?){0,8}(?:[^#]*#[^#]*)?\)[,;]\s*$
```

which would match a line like:

```
(#text1#,#text2#,#text3#,#text4#),
```

or a line like:

```
(#text1#,#text2#,#text3#,#text4#,#),
```

edit: the comma needs to be optional...

[image]

It looks like your new examples no longer are one-per-line, and you no longer have the "single #" case, so it can be simplified to:

```
\((?:[^#\n]*?#[^#\n]*?#[,\s]?){0,8}\)[,;]\s*
```

Comment: Thanks Codebender :-) I figure the problem were the (m) added white space - /^\((?:#.+#,\s*){8}(?:#.+#\s*)\)[,;]$/gm < this works and deletes the whole text - hmmm but it also deletes the error ones?

var htstring29 = ''+stripped28+'';
var stripped29 = htstring29.replace(/^\((?:#.+#,\s*){8}(?:#.+#\s*)\)[,;]$/gm, '');

Comment: This one doesn't quite work due to + (probably) being a greedy quantifier.  I would try `/^\((?:#.+?#,\s*){8}(?:#.+?#\s*)\)[,;]$/gm`

Comment: I have created the sample on this page and cannot get it to work - can you maybe see if you can get it to work ? http://online-affiliate-programs.co.za/test/index.asp

Comment: Your page seems to be un-escaping the regex and breaking it.  Probably something to do with accepting the string as a parameter.  http://codebender.net/so/1218103.html

Comment: Hi Codebender thank you for the time that you spend on assisting me with a solution - \((?:[^#\n]*?#[^#\n]*?#[,\s]?){0,8}\)[,;]\s* <<< works 100% I think the thing I learned most from the excersise were the www.radsoftware.com.au builder :-) Thanks 100 Million - I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem.  Actually I generally use Expresso, but it's not free and I only have it registered on my own computer.

Comment: Will have a look at it - Thanks - Another question regarding the solution that you have provided, lets say I want to use the string to delete all the ones not mathing - smaller but now I want to also match any string bigger than 9 and also delete it?

Comment: Like everything smaller /\((?:[^#\n]*?#[^#\n]*?#[,\s]?){0,8}\)[,;]\s*/ig (this removes everything smaller) so I can do this in one line and in another I want to delete everything bigger - this should leave me with only the results that pass the test?

Any ideas on how to format it - thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to check for "less or more than 9".  I would do it in two passes, once with "{0,8}" and again with "{10,}" (ten or more).  You could also use {9} to match all the valid lines and join them back into a new string.

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with this:

```
/^\(([\s]*#[^#]+#,?){9}\)[,;]$/
```

**edit**:

In perl, if you want to remove occurrences of any pattern of your above set that has less than 9 `#\d#`'s, you can use the following:

```
$string =~ s/\(([\s]*#[^#]+#[\s]*,?){0,8}\)[,;]*//g;
```

It allows for spaces at either end of the `#\d#`, an optional comma separating them within the parens, and either a comma or a semi after the group.  Your resulting `$string` will be the list of 9-token groups from your input string, as they appear in the original.

Comment: I have created an interactive version of what I am looking for at http://online-affiliate-programs.co.za/test/index.asp can you maybe see if you can figure it out, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\((#\w+#,?\s?){9}\)$/ matches exactly 9.
```

Comment: with a potentially broken 10th element due to the ,?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting from the string has some complications, such as what to do with the error line if it is last - contains the ;

```
line = ^\s*\(.*\)[,;]\s*$
a string token = #[\w\s]*#
a list of tokens = token(?:\s*,\s*token)
7 or less items {0,7}
a list of 8 or less tokens = token(?:\s*,\s*token){0,7}
```

Making

```
^\s*\(#[\w\s]*#(?:\s*,\s*#[\w\s]*#){0,7}\)\s*[,;]\s*$
```

with which you want to replace these lines with nothing globally treating the string as multiple lines
/match/replace/gm

```
/^\s*\(#[\w\s]*#(?:\s*,\s*#[\w\s]*#){0,7}\)\s*[,;]\s*$//gm
```

If you have set your string character to # for the purpose of the insert then the token could be simplified to #[^#]+#

In your example short line the last token only has the one # which I have not allowed for here so far, nor an entirely empty element which might be acceptable to your sql parser.

Comment: Hi Greg
Thanks for the comment
Yes what I am trying to do is to delete everything that is not

('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'),  - where the numbers are text/url's etc. I have used the # instead of ' to delete all " ' " like bob's when inserting into the database, so in a next move I replace # with '

This is always there ( and it always ends with ), but the values inside is not always the same I figured I could first delete all the ('1'), and then the ('1','2'), up ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'), untill it leaves the ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')