# Remove lines containing more than X values, using regex

Tags: regex

I am building an Mysql insert with regex.

This is what the insert looks like so far:

```
(#text1#,#text2#,#text3#,#text4#,#text5#,#text6#, #text7#, #text8#, #text9#), (#text1#,#text2#,#text3#,#text4#,#text5#,#text6#, #text7#, #text8#, #text9#), (#text1#,#text2#,#text3#,#text4#,#text5#,#text6#, #text7#, #text8#, #text9#);
```

In a previous question someone helped me to write this regex expression to delete a value that is smalled than the example above

```
var stripped30 = htstring30.replace(/\((?:[^#\n]*?#[^#\n]*?#[,\s]?){0,8}\)[,;]\s*/ig, '');
```

This will remove the exception below and delete it, leaving me with only the 9 tables that I want.

```
(#text1#,#text2#,#text3#,#text4#,#text5#,#text6#),
```

Now I basically want to do the same thing but this time delete all the exceptions bigger than 9 - Can anybody please assist me to do this.

```
(#text1#,#text2#,#text3#,#text4#,#text5#,#text6#, #text7#, #text8#, #text9#),
(#text1#,#text2#,#text3#,#text4#,#text5#,#text6#, #text7#, #text8#, #text9#,  #text10#),
(#text1#,#text2#,#text3#,#text4#,#text5#,#text6#, #text7#, #text8#, #text9#,  #text10#,  #text11#);
(#text1#,#text2#,#text3#,#text4#,#text5#,#text6#, #text7#, #text8#, #text9#),
(#text1#,#text2#,#text3#,#text4#,#text5#,#text6#, #text7#, #text8#, #text9#),
(#text1#,#text2#,#text3#,#text4#,#text5#,#text6#, #text7#, #text8#, #text9#);
```

So that when there is an exception bigger than 9 that I may delete it

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regular expression to remove every line that has not 9 entries:

```
/^(?!\s*\((?:#[^#\n]*#(?:\s*,\s*#[^#\n]*#){8})\)[,;]\s*$).*/mg
```

Comment: I have tried it but it deleted everything /^(?!\s*\((?:#[^#\n]*#(?:\s*,\s*#[^#\n]*#){8}\)[,;]\s*$).*[^;];?$/mg I have received an error when initially using it, /^(?!\s*\((?:#[^#\n]*#(?:\s*,\s*#[^#\n]*#){8}\)[,;]\s*$)).*[^;];?$/mg and added a closing bracket

Comment: +1 Yup, this one correctly removes both "too long" and "too short" records.

Answer (score 0):

you could try the following:

```
var stripped30 = htstring30.replace(/\((?:[^#\n]*?#[^#\n]*?#[,\s]?){10,}\)[,;]\s*/ig, '');
```

where the blank after the `10,` indicates that there is no upper bound.

**edit:**

using [my answer from the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218103/regex-a-expert-should-solve-this-in-seconds/1218116#1218116), but updating it as I have to your example above, produces, for me, good results:

```
\(([\s]*#[^#]+#[\s]*,?){10,}\)[,;]*
```

let me know how you fare.

Comment: Hi AKF I have tried your solution and it is not working either, althoug it actually shows me all the ones that is not matching the problem... but deleting the ones that I want to keep... so if it could be reversed as it is, it may actually work